# Frame Elevation on Visual="Material" Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, material-design

Tried to apply the new Material Visual to the Frame inside a page of my app and it worked okay, but setting the elevation via renderer is not working.

On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) documentation page is said that I should mark the renderer with this `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(SombraMaterialFrameRenderer), new []{typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual)})]` assembly tag, but it does not work, and if I remove the `new []{typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual)}` part it applies only to the regular Frame without the Visual="Material" mark.

Summarizing I need a way to use a renderer with a Visual mark on the element.

Another Reference: [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/beautiful-material-design-android-ios/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral)

Comment: Did you tried this https://github.com/contrix09/XF-Material-Library?

Comment: Yes, this is what we use now on the project, we are trying to implement to the native Material that was released for Xamarin recently.

Comment: Could share a demo about it?

Comment: I cannot share my actual code, because it is protected by copyright, I'll share the thing that I was trying and also how I did a work around.

To summarize, I have just used the MaterialRenderers that Xamarin has crated and inherited it to my own renderer, overwriting the Default ones, and making me able to add my own functionality.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your sharing.